# read a json file with .ajax() using an external url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am overwhelmed, I can't read an external url (http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/geojson/1.0/hour) which contains geoJSON string. I attempted using this script:

```
.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/geojson/1.0/hour',
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data) {
 alert(data.features[0].properties.mag);
 } 
 });
```

I also attempted using the URL plus '&callback=foo' and setting the foo function.

I don't know what to do in order to read this external url. I would like to read an obtain the json string or as text string. Please give me a hand to solve it.

Comment: You cannot fetch content from URLs in different domains unless that domain is configured with CORS headers to allow it. That one does not seem to be.

Comment: Javascript has a cross domain policy where you simply can't get data from external sites. Unless they use CORS or support JSONP. This one does'nt seem to support neither.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15521572/739897 this will help

Comment: Hello guys, thanx for your reply. Is there any way to do it? Any Ideas?